# Pass custom msbuild target from Solution to Project

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-target

I have a Solution with a large number of associated .csproj files.

Each .csproj file has a `<Target Name="PublishQA">...`.

The build fails when I try to compile the whole solution:

```
> msbuild mysolution.sln /t:PublishQA`
"c:\myproj.sln" (publishqa target) (1) ->
  c:\myproj.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "PublishQA" does not exist in the project. [c:\myproj.sln]
```

When I build the `.csproj` project directly, it builds just fine.

**How do I tell msbuild to pass the target to the project files???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a case you can create seperate targets file which explicitly builds your solution,

```xml
<!-- mytargets.targets file -->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"  
         DefaultTargets="MyTargets" 
         InitialTargets="MyTargets">

    <Target Name="MyTargets">
       <MSBuild Projects="MySolution.sln" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

So now you should be able just calling it like

> msbuild.exe mytargets.targets